# How to make a basic authentication in web service soap in Mule ESB?

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, basic-authentication

I am wanting to consume soap webservice, only he has basically authentication. When I try to access is returning:

Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:

Have tried putting the username and password in the url, but it worked: 
username:password@localhost:port

How can I do authentication in web service?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.1/mule-spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="userService">
                    <ss:user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
            name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>

    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer"
        wsdlLocation="host wsdls"
        service="BAPI_VENDOR_FINDService" port="BAPI_VENDOR_FINDPortType"
        serviceAddress="host service"
        doc:name="Web Service Consumer" />
    <flow name="sapFlow1" doc:name="sapFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="hostname to webservice"
            port="8000">
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule"/>
            </http:outbound-endpoint>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="BAPI_VENDOR_FIND"
            doc:name="Web Service Consumer" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Update flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">

    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND" service="BAPI_VENDOR_FINDService" port="BAPI_VENDOR_FINDPortType" serviceAddress="http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/rfc" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>

    <flow name="sapFlow1" doc:name="sapFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" operation="BAPI_VENDOR_FIND"/>
        <logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Log:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6a7be687.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6a7be687 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6a7be687.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/C:/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0.ee_3.5.0.201403072147/mule/tooling/tooling-support-3.5.0-M4.jar!/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/C:/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0.ee_3.5.0.201403072147/mule/tooling/tooling-support-3.5.0-M4.jar!/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, console].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "console".
log4j: Parsed "console" options.
log4j: Parsing for [com.mycompany] with value=[DEBUG].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category com.mycompany set to DEBUG
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.mycompany=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.springframework.beans.factory] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category org.springframework.beans.factory set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.springframework.beans.factory=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category org.apache set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [Tracking] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category Tracking set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.Tracking=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.jetel] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category org.jetel set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.jetel=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.mule] with value=[INFO].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category org.mule set to INFO
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.mule=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [com.mulesoft] with value=[INFO].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category com.mulesoft set to INFO
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.mulesoft=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog] with value=[ERROR].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog set to ERROR
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
Deploying application: sap
Reading plugins from: C:/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0.ee_3.5.0.201403072147/mule/plugins
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:00,828 [main] com.mulesoft.mule.plugin.manager.MulePluginManager: Registering plugin: anypoint-plugin-5.0.2.GA
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:00,841 [main] com.mulesoft.mule.plugin.manager.MulePluginManager: Registering plugin: mule-plugin-debugger-3.5.0-M4
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:01,038 [main] com.mulesoft.habitat.agent.AnypointAgentUtils: Anypoint Service Registry Agent is DISABLED. Property anypoint.agent.token is missing or empty.
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:01,101 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer: ================== New Exploded Artifact: sap
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:01,247 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'sap'                                            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:01,257 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'sap'                                   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:02,432 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:02,893 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@cb6c1e9: startup date [Tue Apr 29 12:57:02 GMT-03:00 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:07,563 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
WARN  2014-04-29 12:57:07,663 [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor: Invalid JavaBean property 'port' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(int)]
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:07,998 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: connector.http.mule.default
Retrieving document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:08,304 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:08,306 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:08,315 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: connector.http.mule.default
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:08,316 [main] org.mule.util.monitor.ExpiryMonitor: disposing monitor
ERROR 2014-04-29 12:57:08,430 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.parseWsdl(WSConsumer.java:263)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.initialise(WSConsumer.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:133)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:88)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:170)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:269)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(ArchiveDeployer.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(ArchiveDeployer.java:257)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(ArchiveDeployer.java:110)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:144)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:128)
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:08,436 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'sap' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2014-04-29 12:57:08,568 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'sap', see below               +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:177)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:269)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(ArchiveDeployer.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(ArchiveDeployer.java:257)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(ArchiveDeployer.java:110)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:144)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:128)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'sapFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:170)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'sapFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'sapFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:113)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:133)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:88)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sapFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.parseWsdl(WSConsumer.java:267)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.initialise(WSConsumer.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.parseWsdl(WSConsumer.java:263)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@host:8000/sap/bc/soap/wsdl11?services=BAPI_VENDOR_FIND
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more
INFO  2014-04-29 12:57:08,581 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Then hire someone who is. Or describe your problem if you expect us to help you with it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. 'll improve.

Comment: What is the problem with doing username:password@localhost:port?

Comment: @Bartdude It was clear now?

Comment: @AntonKupias Sorry, I edited while you answered yes tried and failed

Comment: I asked "what is the problem". How did you configure your http outbound? That is the correct form to configure an address with basic auth, but we can not really guess what you are doing wrong, or help you in debugging this, unless you describe more exactly what you have done, how you have failed, and preferably share your relevant configuration code.

Comment: @AntonKupias i put the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your ws:consumer-config like this for basic auth:

```
serviceAddress="http://username:password@address"
```

To verify this works, you can create another flow with http-inbound, set the serviceAddress address part to that address, and use `<logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` to print the Basic auth and other headers. You should see something like `Authorization=Basic`...  there when you run it.

What I don't understand in your configuration is the `http:outbound-endpoint` with a security filter. Maybe that is the problem? What are you actually trying to accomplish with it? The security filter is used for **http-inbound**, in order to protect it with authentication, and you do not need an extra http-outbound to use the ws consumer.

Comment: It did not work, and did not show the Basic, updated the question with the flow I tested it and log out. 

The serviceAddress is different from wsdlLocation. Tested in only two and only one, and still did not work. 

thank you

Comment: OK, so you have a problem retrieving the wsdl? You can always download a copy to your app resources folder and use that instead.

Comment: Thank you! Worked putting the file locally! You mean you did not work because the authentication does not work in wsdlLocation when he fetches the WSDL, is not it?

Comment: The error stack trace says it fails with http 401 inside a method `readWSDL`. I have never used this component with the WSDL behind authentication, so I really don't know if this is a bug or a missing feature. This is "Early Access" stuff, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can write Component class which can do basic authentication for you.